# How to remove part of a data string?

Tags: python, list, extract, python-2.x

My data is in the following format:

```
[{u'value': 7681, u'time': u'2017-07-12T12:15:54.107488923Z'}, {u'value': 
7672, u'time': u'2017-07-12T12:26:01.295268409Z'}]
```

I need to remove all the **`u`** prefixes from this data. How can I do that using Python 2.7? In fact, I want it to be like:

```
[{'value': 7681, 'time': '2017-07-12T12:15:54.107488923Z'}, {'value': 
7672, 'time': '2017-07-12T12:26:01.295268409Z'}]
```

Comment: What format is that? It's not valid Python syntax.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? (Because that determines how CVS files need to be opened).

Comment: I use python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what `ResultSet` is and its format from your question, however the following example code might be helpful:

```
import csv

csv_filename = 'result_set.csv'
ResultSet = {"(u'maxbotix_depth', None)": [{u'time': u'2017-07-12T12:15:54.107488923Z',
                                            u'value': 7681},
                                           {u'time': u'2017-07-12T12:26:01.295268409Z',
                                            u'value': 7672}]}

with open(csv_filename, mode='wb') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for obj in ResultSet["(u'maxbotix_depth', None)"]:
        time, value = obj[u'time'], obj[u'value']
        print('time: {}, value: {}'.format(time, value))  # optional
        writer.writerow((time, value))
```

Printed output:

```
time: 2017-07-12T12:15:54.107488923Z, value: 7681
time: 2017-07-12T12:26:01.295268409Z, value: 7672
```

Contents of file created:

```
2017-07-12T12:15:54.107488923Z,7681
2017-07-12T12:26:01.295268409Z,7672
```

Comment: Thank you. it works for me.